# CharacterController.Move Jumping Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have been using `CharacterController.Move` to control my fps character.
I have ran into a problem where my character does small jumps when I press <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>s</kbd> and look down or up respectively. My code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
public class PlayerMovement : NetworkBehaviour
{    
    public CharacterController controller;
     
    public float speed = 12f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
      if(IsOwner)
      {

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
      
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
      }
    }
}
```

I cannot find anything on the matter online, so I came here.
I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Please clarify your meaning of jumping. Send video and photos if you can. Nothing is specified in this code. jump is not seen either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code is using the transform's rotation to determine direction of movement. If you look up or down, then your `transform.forward` is also likely directed up or down.

```
   Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
```

So when you look up and apply a positive z value, your movement is going to move you forward *(in the direction you are looking, which is actually up)*. Due to gravity, you are likely making tiny "jumps" as your character moves up and is pulled down by gravity.

There are a few ways to correct for this, but one potential fix would be to remove the y component of your move vector:

```
    move.y = 0f;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and for the explanation (quite new in unity and programming in general)!
It worked like a charm.